# Displaying top five solutions SCIP

Tags: scip

I have written an integer programming model and solved it using SCIP. I can easily obtain the optimal solution but I am interested in also getting the next four best solutions as well. I can type in display allsolutions to show me some solutions in the SCIP shell but I'm interested at at most 4 other solutions and would like to do this from a c++ program rather than from the shell. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the solution methods provided by scip.h to do so:

```
#define SOLSTOPRINT 5;

SCIP* scip;
SCIP_SOL** sols;
int nsols, i;

// ...
// put here your code to create a SCIP instance, read in a problem and call the 
// the solving method of SCIP
// ...

sols = SCIPgetSols(scip);
nsols = SCIPgetNSols(scip);

for( i = 0; i < MIN(nsols, SOLSTOPRINT); ++i )
{
     SCIP_CALL( SCIPprintSol(scip, sols[i], NULL, FALSE) );
}
```

SCIP stores the solutions automatically from best to worst, so that it suffices to iterate over the first 5 solutions of the `sols`-array. Please note that SCIP by default stores at most the 
best 100 solutions found. You can change this behavior through the parameter `limits/maxsol`, e.g., by adding the line

```
SCIP_CALL( SCIPsetIntParam(scip, "limits/maxsol", 200) );
```

to the above code *before* solving the problem.

Comment: Thank you! I had been stuck on this for a while.